# Aria hidden property not working on Mac 10.12.6 Safari 10.1.2

Tags: safari, hidden, wai-aria, voiceover

Content inside Aria hidden attribute is read by voice over but earlier on Mac 10.12 Safari 10.1.1 it was not read by voice over. So any idea what changes took place in this safari version upgrade such that voice over is reading that hidden content.

Comment: Do you have a URL where we can test it and see the code?

Comment: This is happening for me as well, in Chrome and Safari. 
A simple example: https://codepen.io/laras126/pen/GvVEBY
Or more complex at http://nl.nlstage.co - I have a typing effect that is duplicating content, and the duplicated content is hidden with aria-hidden but still being read.

Comment: I'm also seeing this, with Mac 10.12 and Safari 11.0.2.  I know something about the Mac 10.12 + Safari + Voiceover combo is going wrong (I've seen crashes due to that combo), but I'd like to know if there's a fix for this specific "ignores aria-hidden" problem. I'm looking at a span inside a td inside a table inside a modal.  Can't seem to reproduce it by just adding aria-hidden with the dev console.