# aria-hidden attribute not working in react JSX

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx, accessibility

I want only SOME_TEXT to be read by screen reader but it is reading it along with the "*". Here's what I am doing.
I am using safari on mac to test.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <h6> {SOME_TEXT} <span aria-hidden="true">*</span> </h6>
</div>
```

Comment: Seeing an asterisk, which usually indicates a required field, inside an aria-hidden, and also inside a `<h6>`, makes me wonder. I suppose in your productive code you do include the “required” text for screen readers, and actually use `<label>` elements or other means to relate an input with its label? (:

Comment: Could this be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45939088/aria-hidden-property-not-working-on-mac-10-12-6-safari-10-1-2?